# How to find the cause of sudden Undo TableSpace increase?

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle10g, tablespace

I use Oracle R12.1.3 on Oracle 10g DB 10.2.0.4 version hosted in IBM AIX 5.3 OS.

Recently I found the data occupied in Undo TableSpace was suddenly increased.

Please let me know what can be the cause of this sudden increase.

If there is a query to find this cause please let me know.

Comment: If the undo tablespace grows that means you have large, long running transactions.

Answer (score 1):

The below query will give the queries which were executed in last hour.

More rows_processed means more undo for DMLs.

```
select rows_processed, sql_id, sql_text from v$sql where last_active_time > sysdate-1/24 order by rows_processed  desc;
```